OpenOCD Raspberry pi Bit Bang SWD Error connecting DP cannot read IDR
I am posting my question just as I have posted on the forum of STMicroelectronics.
I had been programming my STM32F407 MCU for almost 6 years using OpenOCD's GPIO Bit bang driver over Raspberry-pi for Serial Wire Debug for almost all kinds of projects. Yesterday, I started developing for the USB device driver on my MCU and after the first flash, I am no longer able to connect to it via OpenOCD GPIO Bit Bang driver.
I am successfully able to do everything using OpenOCD with STLink; however, I am not able to connect to DP, using bit band SWD driver of openocd, even if I mass erase the flash and reset everything using stm32cube programmer first. All the option bytes show that everything is as it should be to allow connecting and writing to flash memory.
Does USB development cause any side effects which I am not aware of ? Did anyone face a similar issue before? My physical connections are not a problem. Sometimes i see messages like Wrong Parity Error. I am not sure why that would appear.
I will be looking forward to some relevant guidelines or pointers to understand this problem.
